# svg image element fallback

Tags: html, image, svg, fallback

I have an image in an svg; The url of the image might be a non-reachable file. Is it possible to have a fallback url in case the original file is not reachable?

```
<svg>
    <image width="150" height="150" xlink:href="http://placehold.it/150.png" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Id search svg fallbacks on css-tricks.com, im on my phone or id write up an answer

Answer (score 0):

Yup sure seems to be.

Tested in Chrome under win7.

```
window.addEventListener('load', mInit, false);

var fallbackImgSrc = "img/girl.png";

function mInit()
{
    var svgImgs = document.querySelectorAll('svg image');
    var i, n = svgImgs.length;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        if (svgImgs[i].clientWidth == 0 && svgImgs[i].clientHeight == 0)
        {
            console.log('failed - replacing');
            svgImgs[i].href.baseVal = fallbackImgSrc;
        }
        else
            console.log('loaded');
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: Classic mistake! I only tested the code with a non-existing image. It failed wonderfully and as expected. Just now, I realized I forgot to test with an existing image - it, er, um, also failed and replaced the (existing) image - though I wouldn't describe the failure as wonderful this time..

Not sure which attribute you'll have to check, or even if there is a way to tell if the image loaded okay. Sorry!